# Why can an overloaded operator return something else than its return-type?

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading

I was practicing for one of my upcoming exams and I came upon a weird piece of code in an exercise. For context, it's one of those exercises where you have to determine whether the code will run or not, what's wrong with it etc. The code that I find weird is the following:

```
class A {
        int x;
public:
    A(int i = 0) { x = i;}
    A operator+(const A& a) { return a.x + x;}
...\\ rest of the code is not relevant
};
```

Naturally, I assumed that the operator would generate an error, because it returns an int value, while its return-type is defined to be class A. However, after plugging the whole example in my IDE, to check whether I was right or not, not only was there no error thrown at the function declaration, but one later addition operation in the code actually "worked"(I'm using quotations marks because the value it returned was garbage, but it didn't throw any errors neither).

Why is this not throwing any errors?

Comment: "rest of the code is not relevant": Are you sure? Then remove that code and run your program. Do you still get garbage output?

Comment: Mark the `A(int)` constructor `explicit` and observe what happens.

Comment: I'm not getting the garbage output anymore; yeah, it seems there was an issue somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int` is implicitly convertible to `A`, via `A(int)` constructor. Your `operator+` in effect performs `return A{a.x + x};`

This is not specific to overloaded operators - whenever an expression of one type is provided where another type is expected, the compiler is looking for ways to implicitly convert the former to the latter.

Comment: As mentioned already this is an implicit conversion. See [implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) for the rules governing implicit conversions. The specific one for this case is the thrid one in the list at that link